# Append two dataframes based on bng Easting / Northing

Tags: python, gis

I have two datasets - one containing pollution data (5,850,000 rows, 4 columns) with granularity of 20m x 20m, based on British National Grid. The other - is a dataset extracted from UK Wards polygons (8,949 rows, 6 columns) containing the corresponding easting and northing coordinates for the Wards.

I am looking to append the corresponding Wards to the pollution data set so I can then pivot and derive the average pollution in those Wards.

I'm totally stumped as to how I go about this. Can I somehow use the Wards dataset as a lookup, using the Easting and Northing grid, then apply that to the pollution dataset? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

These are the head outputs of the two sets:

Pollution:

```
        x       y     conct  year
0  501460  170580  29.56267  2016
1  501460  170600  29.70013  2016
2  501460  170620  29.83565  2016
3  501460  170640  29.97066  2016
4  501460  170660  30.10642  2016
```

Wards:

```
   Ward Code            Ward     bng_e     bng_n   st_areasha   st_lengths
0  E05000026           Abbey  544434.0  184378.0  1247619.421  7858.341145
1  E05000027          Alibon  549247.0  185196.0  1355410.730  6246.797017
2  E05000028       Becontree  546863.0  185869.0  1289740.665  6280.315821
3  E05000029  Chadwell Heath  548266.0  189340.0  3382297.063  9496.484608
4  E05000030       Eastbrook  550774.0  186272.0  3449511.083  8857.773001
```

Is there a way to merge Ward names into the pollution dataframe based on x / y columns and bng_e / bng_n?

Comment: There certainly is. Can you tell us first what x and y represent?

Comment: x and y are the grid Easting and Northing, so x = bng_e and y = bng_n

Comment: You have to workout, for each row in Pollution, if the x/y coord is within the area defined for each row in Wards. How to do the "is within" depends on what st_areash and st_lengths actually represent

Comment: Yes that was my thinking too, but I have no idea how to go about this.